# AlertDialog with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog

I want to create custom dialog with list of some items in my app. Here my code of adapter

Context context;
    ArrayList statusList;

```
public MaritalStatusAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> statusList){
    this.context = context;
    this.statusList = statusList;
    Logger.msg("Reg", ":" + statusList.get(0));
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.spinner_list_item, parent, false);
    Logger.msg("Reg", "here");
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.item.setText(statusList.get(position));
    Logger.msg("Reg", "here");
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return statusList.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.item)
    TextView item;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        Logger.msg("Reg", "heee555y");
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.item)
    public void onClick(){
        Logger.msg("Reg", "heeey");
    }
}
```

I think here all code is fine and it should work as I want.
Here my code of dialog builder

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View dialogView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_alert_dialog, null);

            builder.setView(dialogView);

            RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.rv);

            MaritalStatusAdapter adapter = new MaritalStatusAdapter(getActivity(), maritalStatusList);
            rv.setAdapter(adapter);

            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

            dialog.show();
```

So, this code is displaying me my custom dialog view with my edit text, which was added in xml file, but do not display anything in recyclerView. I am sure that my xml file is ok. However I do not understand why I cannot see my items in my list.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/search"
        android:singleLine="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/vertical_line"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/search" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view1" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

At the top my custom_alert_dialog.xml file, but how I said I think here there is no mistake

Can someone help me or share some good tutorial for such activity. It may be small mistake, by the way.))

Comment: Why are you sure that your xml file is ok? This might be problem with layout params or other things that are impossible to guess if we don't see the layout file. Another problem might be, that your are [not setting any LayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setLayoutManager) to your RecyclerView. But again, this can be done in XML which you haven't posted.

Comment: try ` builder.setView(dialogView);` after setting adapter

Comment: @JosefAdamcik So, you want to say that I should put LayoutManager to my code??

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit I tried it before and it did not help

Comment: @AssetBekbossynov I want to say, that you should add your layout xml for dialog to question, even when you think that it's correct. And yes, try to  set layoutmanager (there is already a response from Ali)

Comment: @JosefAdamcik Ok check my question again. I will mind it next time

Comment: Where did you initialize your `maritalStatusList`? And yes, there is not `LayoutManager` attached to your `RecyclerView` as well.

Comment: @ReazMurshed List is initialization is ok it pass list to my adapter. And adding Layout Manager did not help me

Answer (score 6):

I think you should set a LayoutManager to your recyclerView.
add this line before setting the adapter:

```
rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```

Comment: I thought about it before, but unfortunately it did not work

Answer (score 2):

If someone will find it useful, the mistake was that my RecyclerView height is 0dp, so I changed it to wrap_content. I thought it will expand to its parent size, as it should be according to ConstraintLayout properties.